# Tensorflow: Convert a tensor of shape (100,20,20) to a tensor of shape (None,20,20)

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I would like to convert a Tensor of shape (100,20,20) to a Tensor of shape (None,20,20).

I tried many tensorflow functions but it did not work.

Regards
Raf

Comment: You can't squeeze in 40000 data points (100 * 20 * 20) into a space of 400 (20 * 20)  you can only reshape it to (None, 200, 200)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why would you need to go from a defined shape to an undefined shape? (I understand the need for opposite - but not this). Please provide more context